# Java HashMap: Memory advantage to using Byte vs reference keys?

Tags: optimization, memory, memory-management

This would seem to be obvious, but I just want to confirm that this is as clear-cut as I think it is:

An object reference (under 32-bit Java) takes up 4 bytes.
A Byte (boxed primitive) takes up 1 byte.

A HashMap with many entries, then, would have a considerably smaller memory footprint using Bytes as opposed to references for its keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A `HashMap` with many entries, then, would have a considerably smaller memory footprint using bytes as opposed to references for its keys?

You *can't* use `byte` as the key in a `HashMap`. Java generics don't allow primitive types for type arguments. You can use `Byte`, but then you're just boxing.

If you're *really* trying to use `byte` as a key type, I'd be tempted to have an array of size 256 instead anyway...